# How can I sort a list of buffers according to a buffer-local variable?

Tags: buffers, sorting

I am setting a buffer-local variable called `my/tab-order` in (some) of my buffers.

I have written the following function to return a list of buffers only where my/tab-order has been set and is greater than 0.

```
  (defun my/unsorted-buffer-list ()
    (seq-filter (lambda (buf)
                  (and
                   (local-variable-p 'my/tab-order buf)
                   (> (buffer-local-value 'my/tab-order buf) 0))
                  )
                (buffer-list)))
```

I would now like a new function that sorts this list, according to `my/tab-order` (which is an integer).

I can sort this list by name with this function:

```lisp
  (defun my/sorted-buffer-list ()
    (sort (mapcar #'buffer-name (my/unsorted-buffer-list)) #'string<)))
```

But I can't figure out how to sort by the buffer-local-variable.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you want a function that will return the value of `my/tab-order` in a given buffer. Then you can use that function the same way (well, almost) that you use `buffer-name` to sort the buffers by name.

Since you are applying the function *only* to a list of buffers where `my/tab-order` is defined, we'll dispense with checking whether the value exists and what to do if it does not: we'll assume it's there.

The function is simple:

```el
(defun my/buffer-tab-order (buffer)
   (with-buffer buffer
       (list my/tab-order (buffer-name buffer))))
```

The function returns a two-element list consisting of the tab order of the buffer and its name (since ultimately, the buffer name is what you want).

We need a comparison function that can compare two such lists and tell us which one is smaller. It just needs to compare the tab order of each such list which is the first element:

```el
(defun my/buffer-tab-order< (l1 l2)
   (< (nth 0 l1) (nth 0 l2)))
```

Then we map it across the list of buffers of interest and sort the results, using our comparison function for the two-element list structure:

```el
(defun my/sorted-buffer-list ()
  (sort (mapcar #'my/buffer-tab-order (my-unsorted-buffer-list)) #'my/buffer-tab-order<))
```

This produces the sorted list of `(tab-order buffer-name)` two-element lists. If you just want the buffer names only, just map a `cadr` on the list:

```el
(defun my/sorted-buffer-list ()
  (mapcar #'cadr 
     (sort (mapcar #'my/buffer-tab-order (my-unsorted-buffer-list)) #'my/buffer-tab-order<)))
```

Untested. It should work modulo typos: let me know if you run into problems.

The idea of attaching a sort key to an object, sort by the key value and then strip the sort keys out, is a common (almost ubiquitous) one. Here's an [example](https://ia803404.us.archive.org/0/items/pdfy-MgN0H1joIoDVoIC7/The_AWK_Programming_Language.pdf) from "The AWK Programming Language" from 1988, but it certainly goes back much further.

Comment: Works a charm, and the explanation really helped. Thanks so much. :)